# Use an ephemeral port with socket.io server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am looking for a way to start a socket.io server with an ephemeral port. How can I get an ephemeral port with socket.io server?

Perhaps all I need to do is:

```
const Server = require('socket.io);
const s = new Server('http://localhost');
```

perhaps that will use an ephemeral port, as is?

it so, how can I retrieve the port that socket.io found?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websockets with ephemeral ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069063/websockets-with-ephemeral-ports)

Comment: thanks, pretty non-definitive answer over there - I am looking for an answer specific to socket.io

Answer (score 0):

Your example code would just use the default socket.io port which I believe is 8080

My suggestion would be to just select a port number at random that is within the ephemeral range or a range that you define, and then use this library to check to see if it is available or not.  https://github.com/indexzero/node-portfinder

You could also just step through ports in a loop to try and get the lowest available to bind to.  Use portfinder to assure it is available and then use that.

This also have the secondary advantage of being able to then tell you what port was used.

Comment: that's awesome thanks a ton, it was hard for me to find info on this, that should work